# dropzone with jquery and its options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone for file attachment and upload,
I dont want to bind dropzone with form elements as i can not put form inside form,

So i binded it to div element using jquery,

I can upload document correctly with this, but i can not find any way to give options when using as jquery,

below are my codes,

I had binded dropzone as class and ID,
If i remove class, then dropzone is not attaching to div and i can not attach file.

```
 <div class="dropzone" id="dropzoneattach">

 </div>
```

Here is Jquery,

```
$("#dropzoneattach").dropzone({ 
paramName : 'userfile',
url: "<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/news/add_attachments",
});
```

why i am binding with this, because i want file name which uploads as userfile, not file.

While doing this way, i can not upload file,

If there anything wrong? How to give dropzone options when dropzone is creating programatically, i tried to look in documentation but could not understood,

Thanks advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found myself,
Below is just binded with class,

```
$(".dropzone").dropzone({ 
paramName : 'userfile',
url: "<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/news/add_attachments"
)}
```